# Sending component as response to POST request

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, post, lazy-loading

I have a **ReactJS** front-end with **ExpressJS** server, where I would like to implement **component lazy loading**.

**CURRENT BEHAVIOUR:**
After user clicks on the "log in" button there is a fetch POST API called sending user credentials to the server which do the authentication and then responds with user profile data which are then stored in Redux store.

**PLANNED BEHAVIOUR:**
Instead of server sending only user profile data in the response object, there needs to be also ReactJS application component which will be then mounted on the front-end and will allow user to use the app.

**THE QUESTION:**
Is it possible to send the separate webpack bundle file for the component in the response JSON object and if so, how?

Thank you!

Comment: You can take the server's response data and check in `componentWillRecieveprops` function of the component and redirect to the specific route.

Comment: There is no point of sending component from the express server. Webpack alone is capable of doing the lazy load. You can use packages like react-loadable or loadable-components for the lazy loading purpose.

Comment: @AkhilP I get your point, however there is point of sending component from the express server -> time saving. Instead of two synchronous requests it is done all in one.

Comment: That's just one call to the server. But look at the complexity of the program that you have to write. It's literally nothing. But I don't know your case.

Comment: @AkhilP It is not. When you lazy load component you are doing 2nd request because you need to download the 2nd webpack bundle unless you download all the parts on the first run which is not very "first-load" friendly.

Comment: I also meant same. That you need to make an extra server call for getting the bundle file, other than the api call.

Comment: @AkhilP Well then why you are against my approach?

Comment: I'm not against your approach. It's the best approach possible. But by only reducing one server call will not make much defference. And I guess your to get approach done we may need to do lot of coding. Like you need to figure out which bundle you have to send to the user based on the route.